# Show and Hide class (onClick)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

UploadI am using a glyphicon from Bootstrap 3 on a button, which spins with a CSS3 Keyframe, I am wanting to (.hide) this class, untill the button is clicked, then it will appear/show, and spin away...animate as it does?

Here is my Fiddle:

[http://jsfiddle.net/DannyJardine/8djrcwnb/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/DannyJardine/8djrcwnb/1/)

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span>
Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use css for this sort of functionality, and use jQuery's `toggleClass` property:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
   $('.togglable').toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
button {
  height: 50px; /*just some styling for the button*/
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px white, inset -2px -2px 10px black;
  outline: none;
}
.togglable {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 1s; /*speed of animation*/
  transform-origin:center center;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.active {
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  transform: rotate(720deg); /*multiple of 360 to ensure animation finishes 'straight'*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button></button>
<div class="togglable active">Press the red button to toggle me!!!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using Show n hide JQuery..Trial and Error

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.glyphicon-refresh-animate').hide();
});

$("button").click(function(){
$(".glyphicon-refresh-animate").show();
});
```

Thanks for you all your help...